# Sidekiq jobs aren't firing in development mode, only in production

Tags: ruby-on-rails, docker, sidekiq, rails-activejob

Edit: I was just told by our team that docker is not even used for production. So it seems the issue is limited to Docker and not the environments that Rails is launching into.

I have a project I'm working on sidekiq jobs seem to run fine in our production environment, but in my local development machine I get a bunch of console errors for sidekiq and I'm not sure why.

Here are my sidekiq errors:

```
sidekiq_1  | 2017-03-15T17:16:24.346Z 1 TID-gq075lic0 INFO: Booting Sidekiq 4.2.3 with redis options {:url=>"redis://redis:6379/"}
sidekiq_1  | 2017-03-15T17:16:25.240Z 1 TID-gq075lic0 INFO: Running in ruby 2.3.1p112 (2016-04-26 revision 54768) [x86_64-linux]
sidekiq_1  | 2017-03-15T17:16:25.240Z 1 TID-gq075lic0 INFO: See LICENSE and the LGPL-3.0 for licensing details.
sidekiq_1  | 2017-03-15T17:16:25.241Z 1 TID-gq075lic0 INFO: Upgrade to Sidekiq Pro for more features and support: http://sidekiq.org
sidekiq_1  | 2017-03-15T17:16:25.260Z 1 TID-gq075lic0 INFO: Loading Schedule
sidekiq_1  | 2017-03-15T17:16:25.260Z 1 TID-gq075lic0 INFO: Schedule empty! Set Sidekiq.schedule
sidekiq_1  | 2017-03-15T17:16:25.264Z 1 TID-gq075lic0 INFO: Schedules Loaded
sidekiq_1  | 2017-03-15T17:16:25.266Z 1 TID-gq075lic0 WARN: {"context":"Exception during Sidekiq lifecycle event.","event":"startup"}
sidekiq_1  | 2017-03-15T17:16:25.266Z 1 TID-gq075lic0 WARN: TypeError: can't dup NilClass
sidekiq_1  | 2017-03-15T17:16:25.267Z 1 TID-gq075lic0 WARN: /usr/local/bundle/gems/sidekiq-scheduler-2.0.19/lib/sidekiq-scheduler/schedule.rb:126:in `dup'
sidekiq_1  | /usr/local/bundle/gems/sidekiq-scheduler-2.0.19/lib/sidekiq-scheduler/schedule.rb:126:in `block in prepare_schedule'
sidekiq_1  | /usr/local/bundle/gems/sidekiq-scheduler-2.0.19/lib/sidekiq-scheduler/schedule.rb:125:in `each'
sidekiq_1  | /usr/local/bundle/gems/sidekiq-scheduler-2.0.19/lib/sidekiq-scheduler/schedule.rb:125:in `prepare_schedule'
sidekiq_1  | /usr/local/bundle/gems/sidekiq-scheduler-2.0.19/lib/sidekiq-scheduler/schedule.rb:40:in `schedule='
sidekiq_1  | /gathrly/config/initializers/scheduler.rb:5:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
sidekiq_1  | /usr/local/bundle/gems/sidekiq-4.2.3/lib/sidekiq/util.rb:54:in `block in fire_event'
sidekiq_1  | /usr/local/bundle/gems/sidekiq-4.2.3/lib/sidekiq/util.rb:52:in `each'
sidekiq_1  | /usr/local/bundle/gems/sidekiq-4.2.3/lib/sidekiq/util.rb:52:in `fire_event'
sidekiq_1  | /usr/local/bundle/gems/sidekiq-4.2.3/lib/sidekiq/cli.rb:79:in `run'
sidekiq_1  | /usr/local/bundle/gems/sidekiq-4.2.3/bin/sidekiq:12:in `<top (required)>'
sidekiq_1  | /usr/local/bundle/bin/sidekiq:17:in `load'
sidekiq_1  | /usr/local/bundle/bin/sidekiq:17:in `<top (required)>'
sidekiq_1  | /usr/local/bundle/gems/bundler-1.14.6/lib/bundler/cli/exec.rb:74:in `load'
sidekiq_1  | /usr/local/bundle/gems/bundler-1.14.6/lib/bundler/cli/exec.rb:74:in `kernel_load'
sidekiq_1  | /usr/local/bundle/gems/bundler-1.14.6/lib/bundler/cli/exec.rb:27:in `run'
sidekiq_1  | /usr/local/bundle/gems/bundler-1.14.6/lib/bundler/cli.rb:335:in `exec'
sidekiq_1  | /usr/local/bundle/gems/bundler-1.14.6/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/lib/thor/command.rb:27:in `run'
sidekiq_1  | /usr/local/bundle/gems/bundler-1.14.6/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/lib/thor/invocation.rb:126:in `invoke_command'
sidekiq_1  | /usr/local/bundle/gems/bundler-1.14.6/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/lib/thor.rb:359:in `dispatch'
sidekiq_1  | /usr/local/bundle/gems/bundler-1.14.6/lib/bundler/cli.rb:20:in `dispatch'
sidekiq_1  | /usr/local/bundle/gems/bundler-1.14.6/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/lib/thor/base.rb:440:in `start'
sidekiq_1  | /usr/local/bundle/gems/bundler-1.14.6/lib/bundler/cli.rb:11:in `start'
sidekiq_1  | /usr/local/bundle/gems/bundler-1.14.6/exe/bundle:32:in `block in <top (required)>'
sidekiq_1  | /usr/local/bundle/gems/bundler-1.14.6/lib/bundler/friendly_errors.rb:121:in `with_friendly_errors'
sidekiq_1  | /usr/local/bundle/gems/bundler-1.14.6/exe/bundle:24:in `<top (required)>'
sidekiq_1  | /usr/local/bundle/bin/bundle:22:in `load'
sidekiq_1  | /usr/local/bundle/bin/bundle:22:in `<main>'
sidekiq_1  | 2017-03-15T17:16:25.268Z 1 TID-gq075lic0 INFO: Starting processing, hit Ctrl-C to stop
web_1      | Puma starting in single mode...
web_1      | * Version 3.6.0 (ruby 2.3.1-p112), codename: Sleepy Sunday Serenity
web_1      | * Min threads: 5, max threads: 5
web_1      | * Environment: development
web_1      | * Listening on tcp://0.0.0.0:3000
```

It says:

```
sidekiq_1  | 2017-03-15T17:16:25.260Z 1 TID-gq075lic0 INFO: Loading Schedule
sidekiq_1  | 2017-03-15T17:16:25.260Z 1 TID-gq075lic0 INFO: Schedule empty! Set Sidekiq.schedule
sidekiq_1  | 2017-03-15T17:16:25.264Z 1 TID-gq075lic0 INFO: Schedules Loaded
```

But then I get a NilClass error.

Here is my scheduler.rb file:

```
require 'sidekiq/scheduler'

Sidekiq.configure_server do |config|
  config.on(:startup) do
    Sidekiq.schedule = YAML.load_file(File.expand_path('../../sidekiq_scheduler.yml', __FILE__))
    Sidekiq::Scheduler.reload_schedule!
  end
end
```

and my sidekiq-scheduler.rb file:

```
UpdateEventbriteJob:
  cron: "*/15 * * * *"
UpdateMeetupJob:
  cron: "*/15 * * * *"
PostEventEmailJob:
  # cron: "0 9 * * *"
  # cron: "*/1 * * * *"
UpdateStatusJob:
  cron: "*/1 * * * *" # Every minute for testing. Plan on every 24 hours
```

I'm testing the `UpdateStatusJob` locally. The other jobs working production and seem to work fine. But Nothing in this scheduler ever fires in develop mode. I would like to test the job out before I kick it up to production. What am I doing wrong?

I should also note I'm running things in docker. Something I don't use too often so I'm not sure if that's impeding things.

Here is the relevant information in my docker-compose file:

```
version: '2'
services:

  ...

  sidekiq:
    build: .
    command: bundle exec sidekiq -C config/sidekiq.yml
    env_file: .env
    links:
      - db
      - redis

  ...
```

Comment: Is it possible the yml file is in a different location on development?

Comment: sidekiq.yml and sidekiq-scheduler.rb are location in /config on the rails app.

Comment: Could the execution path be different. Relative paths are dependent on the current directory when the sidekiq run context is loaded.

Comment: I don't know a whole lot about that. This is a new app and I'm not super familiar with sidekiq. I do know that jobs run in our production stack which is   identical for development and staging. Where would I learn more about that? Staging and production do not use docker, fyi.

Comment: I don't get how it says Schedule loaded but then I get the `dup` error

Comment: `bundle exec sidekiq -C config/sidekiq.yml -e development` and `bundle exec sidekiq -C config/sidekiq.yml -e production -d`

Comment: I was just told by our team that docker is not even used for production. So it seems the issue is limited to Docker and not the environments that Rails is launching into. With that extra info, I think this is strictly a Docker issue and not related to rails environments. I added that information to my post. Sorry for the inconvenience.

Comment: Could it be that in your scheduler yml `PostEventEmailJob` doesn't have any values, only commented out lines? Try to comment out that line as well, or add back one of the `cron` lines and start again.

Comment: @matov, that was the issue!

If you want to put that as an answer I can give you the credit and the rep. I can't believe it was something that simple.

Comment: @Antonio will do, and no problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the scheduler.yml `PostEventEmailJob` doesn't have any values, only commented out lines.

If you change the file to:

```
UpdateEventbriteJob:
  cron: "*/15 * * * *"
UpdateMeetupJob:
  cron: "*/15 * * * *"
PostEventEmailJob:
  cron: "0 9 * * *"
UpdateStatusJob:
  cron: "*/1 * * * *" # Every minute for testing. Plan on every 24 hours
```

it will parse correctly and start Sidekiq.